# How to manually calculate coefficients for Gamma GLM

Tags: r, statistics, glm

The input I'm giving to the GLM function is:

```
glm(family=fam,data=regFrame1,start=starter1,formula=as.formula(paste(yvar,"~.+0")),na.action=na.exclude,y=T)
```

Where the family is Gamma and the link function is identity.

I'm trying to manually reproduce the coefficients from my model where one of them is for example:

```
                                            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
coefficient A                               480.6062   195.2952   2.461 0.013902 *
```

I know the equation I need for coefficient A is:

βA = (XTX)−1XTY

Where y is my dependent variable and x is my independent variable.

In R I write this to produce βA:

```
# x transposed multiplied by x when both are matrices
xtx <- t(x) %*% x
# x transposed multiplied by y when both are matrices
xty <- t(x) %*% y

# we need to inverse xtx 
xtxinv <- solve(xtx, tol=0)
# finally we multiply the inverse of xtx by xty to get betaHat
betaHat <- xtxinv %*% xty
```

betaHat = 148

When I complete this calculation manually I get the coefficient that is produced when running a GLM on the default normal Gaussian family without specifying a family. Which looks like this:

```
glm(data=regFrame1,formula=as.formula(paste(yvar,"~.+0")),na.action=na.exclude,y=T)
```

So the question is how do I tailor my manual calculation to the Gamma family identity link function instead of the Gaussian identity default that is in the `glm.fit` function in R.

The only two differences with my two runs using the glm function are:

- providing the family (Gamma identity)
- giving the model starting values (100 for each column in the dataframe)

I tried to recreate glm.fit function manually to get out the coefficient (beta). When I didn't provide a family or starting values I got the correct answer but when I gave Gamma as the family and identity as the link with starting values I get a much different coefficient.

Comment: The formula would be `family=gamma(link="inverse")` which is the default. Is this your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For linear regression, which is fit with least squares, BA is indeed (XTX)-1XTY. However, for generalized linear regression, BA is fit by iteratively weighted least squares, which is an iterative algorithm. Therefore, there is no direct formula to compute BA. However, we can compute the equivalent of the hat matrix H in linear regression. In linear regression, the hat matrix is H=X(XTX)-1XT. In generalized linear model, the analogy of the hat matrix is H=WX(XTWX)-1XT where W = diag(mu'(XB)). In both cases, Hy give the fitted values, yA. Here is code to demonstrate.

```
#' Test that the two parameterizations of Gamma are the same
curve(dgamma(x, 3, scale=3), xlim=c(0, 10))
grid <- seq(0, 10, length=1000)
d <- 1/grid/gamma(3)*(grid/(1/3)/9)^3*exp(-grid/3)
plot(grid, d, type='l')

#' Generate random variates according to GLM with
#' Y_i ~ Gamma(mean=mu, 
#' squared coefficient of variation (variance over squared mean) = phi)
#' Y_i ~ Gamma(shape=alpha, scale=beta)
#' mu = alpha*beta
#' phi= 1/alpha
#' Let Beta = (3, 4)

set.seed(123)
X <- data.frame(x1=runif(1000, 0, 10))
mu = (3+4*X$x1)^(-1)

y=NULL
for (i in 1:1000) {
  alpha = 1/3
  beta = mu[i] * 3
  y[i]=rgamma(1, alpha, scale=beta)
}

#' Fit the model and compute the hat matrix, then the fitted values manually

mod <- glm(y ~ ., family=Gamma(), data=X)

x <- as.matrix(cbind(1, X))
W=diag(c(-(x%*%c(3, 4))^(-2)))
H=W%*%x%*%solve(t(x)%*%W%*%x)%*%t(x)
#Manual fitted values
head(H%*%y)
#Fitted values from model
head(mod$fitted.values)
```

Comment: But I get the correct coefficient using (XTX)-1XTY when I use default `glm()`:

```glm(data=regFrame1,formula=as.formula(paste(yvar,"~.+0")),na.action=na.exclude,y=T)```


Does this not use IWLS method? Or is that only used with the Gamma family?

Comment: @frankfrankfrank That’s because the Gaussian family with identity link is linear regression.

Comment: Ah perfetct! Thanks for your help. I'll have a go at using the hat matrix H.